# Return css rule value with gradients from SASS function

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

I am having scss below which generates UI as following image. However as you can see lot of code is magic number and repeated I was trying to use sass function to come up with function to get css rule value.

however I realized that only simple number calculations are done with SCSS function and returning complex rule value could be challenging. I would like to know if there is any way possible to get desired result

[image]

```
// Current Code
    $light: white;
    $dark: gray;
    div {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100px;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom,
          $light, $light 90px,

          $dark 90px, $dark 102px,
          $light 102px, $light 105px,

          $dark 105px, $dark 117px,
          $light 117px, $light 120px,

          $dark 120px, $dark 132px,
          $light 132px, $light 135px,

          $light 100%
        )

    }

    // What I am trying to achieve
        @function get-line-skeleton($height-of-bar, $verticle-spacing, $start-at)
    {
       // code to return value of rule with series of auto generated gradient
    }
        $light: white;
        $dark: gray;
        div {
          height: 400px;
          width: 100px;
          background: @get-line-skeleton(12, 3, 90)      
        }
```

Comment: This seems like a particular and complex solution to achieve what you want. Can't you modify the HTML markup or use `:before` or `:after` ?

Comment: Thats an option but I choose CSS only approach to build XHR loading skeletons seems good for simple solutions so far

Comment: Ohh, those are loading skeletons, nevermind then. Wouldn't a mixin be easier then ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a mixin to generate stripes. [Sassmeister demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9ba3174aba59e0b36456657ba97a8c60).

```
@mixin linear-gradient($stripe-size, $stripe-color, $gutter-size, $gutter-color, $count) {

  $stripes: null; // it's like array

  @for $i from 1 through $count {
    $start-position: ($stripe-size + $gutter-size) * ($i - 1);
    $end-posotion: $start-position + $stripe-size;

    $stripe: $stripe-color $start-position, $stripe-color $end-posotion;
    $stripes: append($stripes, $stripe, comma); // `push` gradient step to `array`

    @if ($i != $count) {
      // don't apply gutter after last stripe 
      $gutter: $gutter-color $end-posotion,   $gutter-color $end-posotion + $gutter-size;
      $stripes: append($stripes, $gutter, comma);
    }
  }

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $stripes);
}

div {
  @include linear-gradient(10px, red, 5px, green, 3);
}
```

What's interesting: [@mixins](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin), sass [lists](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/functions/list), [@for loops](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for), [@if rules](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if).

This mixin generates this code:

```css
div {
  height: 40px; /* not from mixin */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0px, red 10px, green 10px, green 15px, red 15px, red 25px, green 25px, green 30px, red 30px, red 40px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```